# toggle css class for two buttons when either is clicked

Tags: css, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 class Buttons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }
   render() {
    return (
      <div className="displayButtons">
        <input className='button1' onClick={this.props.get_menu_items_api} 
        value="Categories" type="button" ref="button"></input>
        <input className='button2' onClick={this.props.get_addons_items_api} 
        value="Add Ons" ref="button1" type="button"></input>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Buttons;
```

I have these two buttons in react class.Their css is given below. What I want to do is on whichever button I click on it should turn orange and other should turn white. Initially Categories button is orange and Addons button is white. 
I tried calling a function onClick that changes its class but how will it change the class of other button also.

```
.button2 { 
  border: none;
  padding: 11px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.button1 {
  background-color:#F6A623;  
  color: white;
}

.button2 {
  background-color:white; 
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the status of the component identifier of the orange button and change it with using onClick.

**Component:**

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      orangeButtonId: null
    }
    this.setOrangeButton = this.setOrangeButton.bind(this);
  }
  setOrangeButton(id){
    this.setState({orangeButtonId: id});
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <input className={this.state.orangeButtonId === 1? "button1 orange" : "button1"} onClick={() => this.setOrangeButton(1)} value="Categories" type="button" ref="button" />
          <input className={this.state.orangeButtonId === 2? "button2 orange" : "button2"} onClick={() => this.setOrangeButton(2)} 
            value="Add Ons" ref="button1" type="button" />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**And styles:**

```
input[type="button"]{
  background-color: white;
}
input[type="button"].orange{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/83389/.

Comment: Thanks alot. This was so easy. I have been struggling with this for hours.

Comment: I have one doubt , How does this sets the other button to white . When I have already applied css to it .input[type="button"]{
  background-color: white;
}

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to keep track of button state within your class. When onClick is called set your state.

   onButton1Click() {
       this.setState({button1Down: true});
   }
2. Then in the render call you need to use this state to set the class names to apply to your buttons.

   render() {

   let button1ClassName = 'button1';

   if (this.state.button1Down) {
          button1ClassName += 'button-down';
      }

   return ...

Answer (score 0):

it can easily achived by using the component inner state + [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library:

```
class Buttons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
     this.state = {
        selectedButton: 'categories'
     }
    }
 onButtonClick(e) {
    this.setState({
       selectedButton: e.target.value
    });
    if (e.target.value === 'categories') {
       this.props.get_menu_items_api();   
    } else {
       this.props.get_addons_items_api();
    }
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div className="displayButtons">
    <input className={classnames({'button': true, 'selected': this.state.selectedButton === 'categories'} onClick={onButtonClick} 
      value="Categories" type="button" ref="button"></input>
    <input className={classnames({'button': true, 'selected': this.state.selectedButton === 'addons'})} onClick={onButtonClick} 
      value="Add Ons" ref="button1" type="button"></input>
   </div>
   )
  }
}
```

Comment: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function- it gives this error.